# Adjoint matrix as pseudo-inverse

Tags: matrices, adjoint-operators, pseudoinverse, transpose

I'm very new to signal processing (seismic 1,2 and 3D-signal) and have read many papers recently. One thing I encounter quite often is the use of adjoint matrix.

If $d = Am$ where $d$ is the data, $A$ is an operator that models a physical process and $m$ is the model, many people define $\widetilde m=A^Td$  or $\widetilde m=A^*d$ be the pseudo-inverse for $m$ and sometimes use $\widetilde m$ as a starting model. I know $A^{-1}=A^T$ sometimes but in general it's not the case. So how good is this pseudo-inverse?

Can someone give me some more insight or give me some reference on this?

Comment: Are you talking about unitary matrices? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2053194/what-is-the-difference-between-transpose-and-inverse/2203220#2203220

Answer (score 4):

There may be some confusion.

The class of matrices for which
$$
 \mathbf{U}^{*} \mathbf{U} = \mathbf{U} \,  \mathbf{U}^{*} = \mathbf{I}
$$
are called **unitary**.

In general, use of the pseudoinverse matrix implies the classical matrix inverse does not exist. (When the classic inverse exists, it is equal to the pseudoinverse).

---

---

To address the concerns of @Michael May:

The Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse is defined and manipulated in the following references.

Your specific question seems to be *when does the transpose of a matrix*, $\mathbf{A}^{*}$, *equal the pseudoinverse of the matrix,* $\mathbf{A}^{+}$?
$$
 \mathbf{A}^{*} = \mathbf{A}^{+} \,  \mathbf{U}^{*} = \mathbf{I}
$$

Given a matrix $\mathbf{A}^{*}\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times n}_{\rho}$, with $\rho \le \min(m,n)$, the singular value decomposition can be expressed in terms of the fundamental subspaces as:
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{A} = 
  \mathbf{U} \, \Sigma \, \mathbf{V}^{*} 
%
 =
% V 
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}} & \color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}
  \end{array} \right]  
% Sigma
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \mathbf{S} & \mathbf{0} \\ %fixed typo here
     \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} 
  \end{array} \right]
% U* 
  \left[ \begin{array}{c}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} \\ 
     \color{red}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{N}}}^{*}
  \end{array} \right]  \\
%
\end{align}
$$

The adjoint matrix is then
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{A}^{*} = 
  \mathbf{V} \, \Sigma^{T} \, \mathbf{U}^{*} 
%
 =
% V 
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}} & \color{red}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{N}}}
  \end{array} \right]  
% Sigma
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \mathbf{S}^{T} & \mathbf{0} \\
     \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} 
  \end{array} \right]
% U* 
  \left[ \begin{array}{c}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} \\ 
     \color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}^{*}
  \end{array} \right]  \\
%
\end{align}
$$
Because the singular values are real, and the matrix is diagonal,
$$
\mathbf{S} = \mathbf{S}^{T}
$$

The Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse is
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{A}^{+} = 
  \mathbf{V} \, \Sigma^{-1} \, \mathbf{U}^{*} 
%
 =
% V 
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}} & \color{red}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{N}}}
  \end{array} \right]  
% Sigma
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \mathbf{S}^{-1} & \mathbf{0} \\
     \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} 
  \end{array} \right]
% U* 
  \left[ \begin{array}{c}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} \\ 
     \color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}^{*}
  \end{array} \right]  \\
%
\end{align}
$$

When does $\mathbf{A}^{*} = \mathbf{A}^{+}$? That is, when does
$$
% V 
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}} & \color{red}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{N}}}
  \end{array} \right]  
% Sigma
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \mathbf{S} & \mathbf{0} \\
     \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} 
  \end{array} \right]
% U* 
  \left[ \begin{array}{c}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} \\ 
     \color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}^{*}
  \end{array} \right] 
%
=
% V 
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}} & \color{red}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{N}}}
  \end{array} \right]  
% Sigma
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \mathbf{S}^{-1} & \mathbf{0} \\
     \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} 
  \end{array} \right]
% U* 
  \left[ \begin{array}{c}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} \\ 
     \color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}^{*}
  \end{array} \right]  ?
%
$$

The equality is satisfied when
$$
\mathbf{S} = \mathbf{S}^{-1} = \mathbf{I}_{\rho}
$$

References:

1. [Pseudoinverse - Interpretation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1245214/pseudoinverse-interpretation/2209513#2209513)
2. [What forms does the Moore-Penrose inverse take...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1537880/what-forms-does-the-moore-penrose-inverse-take-under-systems-with-full-rank-ful/2200203#2200203)
3. [Singular value decomposition proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2209379/singular-value-decomposition-proof/2211001#2211001)
4. [What is the SVD of A−1?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/884859/what-is-the-svd-of-a-1/2334206#2334206)
5. [Pseudo Inverse Solution for Linear Equation System Using the SVD](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49857/pseudo-inverse-solution-for-linear-equation-system-using-the-svd/2242923#2242923)

Comment: What you are saying is for the case of square matrices. What the OP is referring to is when matrix is *not square* and you need to rely on the pseudoinverse.

Comment: @Michael. The analysis here is for the most general case where $m\neq n$. That is, there is no restriction the number of rows must equal the number of columns. The matrix may take arbitrary form.